# can not understand... apache/mariadb/php

Tags: server, apache2, php

I installed Kubuntu 19. After that, I installed Apache2/PHP/MariaDB.
But I can not understand WHY MariaDB and Apache2/PHP are using different authentication modules on the same distribution.
By default, MariaDB has for user_authentication caching_sha2 _password, but by Apache2/PHP is using another availabled password *auth* variables.

My question is that, why this bundle can not work properly out of package?